# How to hide only some text not all inside block element?

Tags: html, css

I have this paragraph on desktop website

```
<p>Original price 225.95
   <span>
      Save 90.38
   </span>
</p>
```

On mobile device I want hide **Original price** and **Save** only

Which should be look like this

225.95
       
          <s>90.38</s>

Is it possible to hide only some words from a paragraph using CSS without making any change in HTML

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Not with pure-CSS anyways. You could get pretty creative with JavaScript though.

Comment: Then I will go for @Parzifal method

Answer (score 2):

No, you would have to enclose the words you would like to hide e.g. in `span` elements:

```
<p><span class="hide">Original price</span> 225.95
    <span>
      <span class="hide">Save</span> 90.38
    </span>
</p>
```

Then define the rule:

```
p .hide {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Yeah I'm aware about this method